# android.net.WifiManager cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have this class in my MainActivity to detect Internet Connection and wifi scanning result. I am getting at the Moment this error "android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS cannot be resolved to a type" at this

inner MainActivity:

```js
class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

   } else if(intent.getAction().equals(android.net.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) { //here is the error
                 }
     }
 }
```

```js
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectionBroadcast" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this The best that worked for me:

**AndroidManifest**

```
<receiver android:name="com.AEDesign.communication.WifiReceiver" >
   <intent-filter android:priority="100">
      <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver class**

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
      if(info != null) {
         if(info.isConnected()) {
            // Do your work. 

            // e.g. To check the Network Name or other info:
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: The Problem is not the code. My code works well too but I just need to put the both broadcat(Internet conection and wifi scan result)in the onReceive(). Therefor, I used the if condition. I dont know how to manage that with the if condition

Comment: check both if and else conditions in one if with && operation. If it not true then it's not connecting with any network.