# Cannot resolve symbol 'setWifiEnabled'

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to turn on wifi on the app launch with this code:

`WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);`

But it marks "setWifiEnabled" red and says "cannot resolve symbol 'setWifiEnabled'". Why does this happen? The only options it gives me are "MulticastLock" and "WifiLock".

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487366/android-net-wifimanager-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Comment: Thanks solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;` and `import android.content.Context;`.

Also you don't need to declare `wifi` twice as type `WifiManager`, you can define `wifi` as an object of type `WifiManager` and then use it.

I also got the hint:

> The WIFI_SERVICE must be looked up on the Application context or
> memory will leak on devices < Android N. To solve it you can change
> getSystemService to getApplicationContext()

So at the end it would look like the following:

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.content.Context;

// in your class
private WifiManager wifi;
wifi =(WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```